# How to rewrite history on gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

Gerrit accidentally introduced some merge commits (configured with "Merge if necessary" option)  and I would like to remove them from the history.
I am aware of the pitfalls of rewriting history when team working with Git, but developers will not suffer from this in our case, as none of them have local changes in this particular repository.

I did a `git rebase -i` locally and Git automatically removed Gerrit's merge commits.
I carefully removed the previous Gerrit Change-Ids in each commit messages and the Gerrit commit message hook added new ones.

`git status` command output:

> On branch master
>   Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
>   and have 7 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
>     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

Which is what I want (9 commits minus the 2 merge commits).

When I try to push on Gerrit with `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` I get no error.
However when I try to review and submit on Gerrit web interface, I get the following error:

> The change could not be merged due to a path conflict.
>   Please rebase the change locally and upload the rebased commit for review.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When rewriting history, you would not push for review (don't push to `refs/for/*`).  You need to push directly to the raw repository (`refs/heads/*`).  This means you will need permissions to bypass review in Gerrit.  I would recommend just giving yourself permissions temporarily and removing them once this is done, so you don't accidentally bypass review in the future.

You will also need to run the `git push` with the `-f` flag to tell git to rewrite history.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I perform the following command : "git push -f origin HEAD:refs/heads/master", I get the error :  ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (non-fast forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://repositories:29418/repository'. I have the following rights on refs/heads/* : Create Reference/Push/Submit. Do I need some more?

Comment: Yes, but the name of the permission depends on your version of Gerrit.  See http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/access-control.html#category_push - Direct push: Force option

Allows an existing branch to be deleted. Since a force push is effectively a delete immediately followed by a create, but performed atomically on the server and logged, this option also permits forced push updates to branches. Enabling this option allows existing commits to be discarded from a project history.